# HttpClient auto logging out when sending post data

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

I have the method sendPost() which sends a post data to login to a certain site. I am able to get the response code of 302. After executing this method, I have a sendPost2() method which will work if I am successfully logged in. However, I get the response code of 200 in sendPost2(), it also tells me that I am not logged in. It seems that after executing sendPost(), the httpclient logs me out. How do you prevent it from logging out?

Here is my sendPost() but I can't give you a valid username and password:

```
private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        String url = "http://sblive.auf.edu.ph/schoolbliz/commfile/login.jsp";

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        // add header
        post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", "testusername"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "testpassword"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("x", "47"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("y", "1"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("body_color", "#9FBFD0"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("welcome_url", "../PARENTS_STUDENTS/main_files/login_success.htm"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login_type", "parent_student"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + post.getEntity());
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + 
                                    response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Comment: When interfacing with a website because HTTP itself is a stateless protocol, websites normally use cookies to store session data. From your code, I don't see anywhere that you are sending the cookies the website expects you to send (behavior of a browser with cookies turned off). Since with every request, you are sending blank cookies, the website assumes you are a entire separate client since the initial POST response. Essentially, you must resend all cookies the website expects you to store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Recipe

- prepare a [`CookieStore`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/CookieStore.html)
- set it in the [`HttpContext`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext.html)
- pass the context to every [`HttpClient#execute()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,%20org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext%29) call

You need the cookie store to have a place to [keep the session ID between calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID).

## Code

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
// ...

HttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(method1, httpContext);
// ...

HttpResponse response2 = httpClient.execute(method2, httpContext);
// ...
```